# MVC4 ViewModel [Required] Annotation not working with UIHINT for a KendoUI Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, viewmodel

I have the following property in a ViewModel:

```
[UIHint("AccessDropDown")]
[Display(Name ="Access Level")]
[Range(1, 2, ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
public int InternalUserAccess { get; set; }
```

AccessDropDown is a `PartialView` which lives in the Views folder, under shared, under EditorTemplates directory. It is a `KendoDropDownList` like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("UserAccess").OptionLabel("Select")
.BindTo(new List<DropDownListItem>
            {
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "User", Value = "1"},
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "Admin", Value = "2"}
            }
))
```

The problem is that despite me adding a `[Required]` annotation on the above property and despite the Range annotation which I also added to solve this; it still doesn't validate - a value of zero is set to the option label instead!

I have tried removing the `OptionLabel` and adding a new item to the list with a value outside the set range such as:

```
new DropDownListItem{Text = "Select", Value = "1564"},
```

But this still didn't validate and the value of 1564 went into the controller to be entered to the database!

Any ideas why a `PartialView` with a `UIHINT` wont 'obey' the validation annotation on the view model?

Please let us know..

Many thanks.

Comment: first of all your concept of validating a dropdownlist is wrong. you are not validating user inputs you have taken this option and are giving them choise to choose from the dropdownlist...simple is that..I do'nt think that you can use DataAnnotations to validate dropdown list values in normal way as well...

Comment: @Shaz so how do I validate user-selections in a dropdown, when one of the options given is only there to show a message of: "Please Select"?

Comment: you simply don't fill the .OptionsLabel("Please select")...dropdownlist will set the 1st option by default for you...and if there was no choice and you have to show "please select" then validate the control on form submitt mate...

Comment: @Shaz as far as I know the OptionLabel doesn't get set by default. I 'll try do the validation on form-submit with JavaScript. thanks.

Comment: to clearly further "Please Select" string is it coming from DB..??? i thought you are using @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.workOrder.ClientName)
                                    .DataTextField("Text")
                                    .DataValueField("Value")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;" })
                                    .OptionLabel("Select Client...")

Comment: @Shaz No, it is set in the declaration of the dropdownlist as you see. it is an Option in KendoUI Dropdownlist. Please have a look at the second set of code above - this is the declaration of the dropdownlist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48684/discussion-between-shaz-and-t-plusplus)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with a regular TextBox Html helper, do you see the validation then? If it does then I would assume that the only problem is that you are using different Name for the widget.

Try to set the name to be either **.Name("InternalUserAccess")**

or make it generic so it becomes the same as the name of the property that you are editing with that editor template

e.g.

```
@model int

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m).OptionLabel("Select")
.BindTo(new List<DropDownListItem>
            {
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "User", Value = "1"},
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "Admin", Value = "2"}
            }
))
```

Comment: the Form where this dropdownlist is, is being auto-generated by a Kendo UI Grid 'Create' button from the view model of the grid. I have tried to rename the dropdownlist in the UIHINT to InternatlUserAccess, it didn't help unfortunately. thank you.